# How do I insert a 1D Torch tensor into an existing 2D Torch tensor into a specific row?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I want to insert a 1D Torch tensor into a specific row number into a 2D Torch tensor (Using Pytorch).

The 1D tensor and the 2D tensor will always have the same length, so you can easily visualize this as a table with rows and columns.
The 2D tensor is the existing table and I would like to be able to specify the the row number the 1D tensor (or row) will be inserted.
When I say I'd like to use Pytorch, I don't want to turn anything into a non-Pytorch list and send the computations back and forth over the CPU and GPU. The tensors are all already on my CUDA device and I would like to keep them there for the sake of time.

The 2D tensor `three_by_four`

```
tensor([[0.7421, 0.1584, 0.3231, 0.4840],
        [0.4065, 0.7646, 0.9677, 0.4537],
        [0.5226, 0.6216, 0.9420, 0.0605]], device='cuda:1')
```

The 1D tensor `one_by_three`

```
tensor([[0.3095, 0.8460, 0.2900, 0.9683]], device='cuda:1')
```

The best I was able to do was get the new row (the 1D tensor) appended to the bottom or top of the 2D tensor with `torch.cat` depending on the order.
The 1D tensor added to the top.

```
torch.cat([one_by_three, three_by_four])  

tensor([[0.3095, 0.8460, 0.2900, 0.9683],
        [0.7421, 0.1584, 0.3231, 0.4840],
        [0.4065, 0.7646, 0.9677, 0.4537],
        [0.5226, 0.6216, 0.9420, 0.0605]], device='cuda:1')
```

The 1D tensor added to the bottom

```
torch.cat([three_by_four, one_by_three])  
tensor([[0.7421, 0.1584, 0.3231, 0.4840],
        [0.4065, 0.7646, 0.9677, 0.4537],
        [0.5226, 0.6216, 0.9420, 0.0605],
        [0.3095, 0.8460, 0.2900, 0.9683]], device='cuda:1')
```

What I would like, for example, if I could put it in position 1, or 2 in this example.

```
tensor([[0.7421, 0.1584, 0.3231, 0.4840],
        [0.4065, 0.7646, 0.9677, 0.4537],
        [0.3095, 0.8460, 0.2900, 0.9683]
        [0.5226, 0.6216, 0.9420, 0.0605]], device='cuda:1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now the best I could find

```py
from torch import tensor, cat
x = tensor([[0.7421, 0.1584, 0.3231, 0.4840],
        [0.4065, 0.7646, 0.9677, 0.4537],
        [0.5226, 0.6216, 0.9420, 0.0605]])
y = tensor([[0.3095, 0.8460, 0.2900, 0.9683]])
cat([x[:1], y, x[1:]])
'''
tensor([[0.7421, 0.1584, 0.3231, 0.4840],
        [0.3095, 0.8460, 0.2900, 0.9683],
        [0.4065, 0.7646, 0.9677, 0.4537],
        [0.5226, 0.6216, 0.9420, 0.0605]])
'''
```

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-insert-a-tensor-into-an-existing-tensor/14642

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wonder if all that is happening in CUDA on the GPU. I wonder if there is a cut and dry way to tell if any of it happened outside of the GPU.

Comment: All of these operations happen on device of input tensors, so if inputs are on GPU then output will be on GPU.

Comment: Will do. I was waiting to see if anyone else would chime in case there was some other way to do this. btw, I could use an upvote too. Thank you again.